# Which "schematic editor" is used here?

Tags: schematics

Kindly help me identify the schematic creator/editor used. [image: Schematic]

Comment: This is Eagle. Also, the bidirectional bipolar junction transistors for open-drain voltage level uses way too many components -- the equivalent circuit with two N-channel MOSFETs is a lot simpler. Also, 10k pull-up for I2C is very weak -- if you want to run at 400 kHz or 1 MHz, you'll need to go to 2.2 kOhm or less.

Comment: Thanks Jon! I feel stupid stating this but I've come across Eagle (schematic editor) on multiple occasions but someone always told me "it is **difficult** to learn", and so I rather used some *other schematic editor*. And today I see a nice/neat schematic on internet and I am intrigued, and I put a question on electronics.stackexchange only to find out that its the one I had once ran away from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This schematic was drawn in CadSoft Eagle.
[Home page](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/eagle-pcb-design-software/?language=en)
[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAGLE_%28program%29)

Comment: Wiki says its license is proprietary but then it also mentions freeware version available. Does that imply there are two versions, a **free version** for everyone and a **commercial version** for professionals/industries ?

Comment: Yes, there is a free version, but it is crippled down to the point where it can't be used for anything of substance. There are a dozen free EDA packages I would use before Eagle.

Comment: @MattYoung  Are you alluding to Eagle's very unusual user interface, which takes a lot of getting used to?

Comment: No, more along the lines of the boards I want to make won't fit into their miniscule free version size/net requirements. But now that you mention it, yeah, the UI sucks.

Comment: @MattYoung I request you to speak the names of those *EDA Packages*. I'm thrilled.

Comment: @vvy Design Spark, KiCad, gEDA for starters, there are a ton more if you are ok using a particular board house.

Comment: just for reference .. try www.Upverter.com